# How can hydrodynamic fluctuations induce repulsive force?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics

The paper https://doi.org/10.1039/C5SM02346G considers a compressible fluid subject to thermal fluctuations and confined between two planar rigid walls. The fluid is modeled with stochastic hydrodynamics (navier-stokes augmented with random noise) to derive spatial autocorrelation function of velocity field.

Without the two rigid walls, the total momentum of the fluid would not fluctuate and would be just zero. But the collision with the walls imply momentum exchange between the fluid and the wall, and therefore one question in the paper is the time-scale and spatial scale of these fluctuations. That was also the reason why I was reading this work.

But in the introduction the authors motivate their work by the possibility of deriving an effective force between the two rigid walls due to thermal fluctuations of the fluid. They refer to van-der-Waals forces as an electrodynamic analogy, *where the fluctuations of two dipoles effectively lead to a long ranged attraction*.  They mention the formal analogy between these two systems, as van-der-Waals force was derived from **stochastic electrodynamics**, while the fluid at thermal equilibrium between rigid walls is described by **stochastic hydrodynamics**.

*But on the intuitive level*,  how can hydrodynamic fluctuations induce repulsive force ? As opposed to the case of fluctuating dipoles leading to effective attraction, I can not really grasp why this should be similar for thermally fluctuating fluid confined between two walls. *How can a static, repulsive long-range force between solid boundaries immersed in a fluctuating fluid result from the fluctuations of the fluid ?*

Comment: I can't find any picture of the system they consider, or verbal description. Is the fluid only in between the walls, or is it on both sides of the walls? In the first case repulsion is quite to be expected - waves are impacting and recoiling off the walls, and if wave packets carry momentum, the result should be repulsion of the walls.

Comment: The fluid is confined between $x=0$ and $x=L$,   the first wall is an infinite plane at $x=0$ and the second wall is an infinite plane at $x=L$. So this would be the first case in your comment. I still do not clearly understand your argument.

Comment: Imagine a surface wave packet on the water moving towards a wall partially submerged in the water, head on. Which direction would you expect the wall to move after the impact? I would expect it to move in direction of propagation of the incoming wave, because I would expect the wave to transport momentum in direction of its propagation. Thus I would expect the wave packet to behave and have the same effect on the wall as a ping-pong ball.

Comment: What *would be* hard to understand intuitively is non-zero net force on the wall in case the fluid was on both sides of both walls. I would then expect an explanation to be in the effect of the other wall, affecting phases of reflected waves.